# Incorrect helpful flags count

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, helpful-flags

I viewed my MSO user profile this morning and noticed that the helpful flags count has dropped from some 30+ (from memory) to just 4:

[image]

I've flagged more than 4 for OT posts in the past few weeks alone. What's happened to them?
(*Triangular freehand shape intentional*)

Comment: Never mind, had to refresh the page to see the linked duplicate.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Seems to have been brewing for a day or two by looking at dupes/thread.